# Getting this error when I try to run jar file that I created : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Appender

Tags: log4j, noclassdeffounderror, appender

I am getting an exception when I try to run the jar file that I created for my java application. I am using log4j for logging purpose and I created a custom log that records per cron job transactions.
Then I have written a shell script where I call the jar file. I have put the properties file outside the jar file.

I am running the jar file through a shell script. The command I use is
*java -jar app.jar $1*

The java application has 2 properties files 
1) app.properties
2) sublog4j.properties

The sublog4j properties file has data like this:

log4j.appender.log=package.CustomFileAppender
log4j.appender.log.File=/serverpath/error.log

I have a gut feeling that I am getting error because of package.CustomFileAppender. It is a java file in app.jar but I don't know how to create a custom appender and use it in the external properties file.

```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:    org/apache/log4j/Appender
   at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
   at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2615)
   at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2856)
   at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1668)
   at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
   at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Appender
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
```

Comment: can you detail how you run your program (java command line, ant, maven ...) and the structure of your project (lib directories, which files added to the lib ...) with those information it will be possible to know if you're missing something

Comment: Could we see your setup?

Comment: @FredericHenri I am running the jar file through shell script. The command I use is : java -jar app.jar $1

Comment: @frenchDolphin I have edited my question and added more details.

Comment: ANY IDEA WHY I AM GETTING THIS ERROR?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error because I was not building the jar file correctly. So what I did is I created an executable jar file and also copied source code when I created the jar. This is how the issue got resolved.